# Angular 5: Data of *ngFor changing after a click on a radio button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

So the issue is , I have an array in `*ngFor` inside a `<tr>`. Inside the row I have multiple `<td>`, first one of which has a radio button.
When the page is loaded the table is rendered normally. After I click on the radio button I get the

> error: Error trying to diff 'on'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

As I click the radio button,  I have also **console.log** the data itself, the data is viewed normally. But the second time I click it the data is 'on'.

Basically the data is changing after the first click on the radio button.

This is the Code :

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of mpFASetupList" [style.background-color]="checkFlag ? 'yellow' : 'white'">
    <td class="data" id="zero">
      <input id="faRadioBtn" type="radio" name="anyName"  (click)="onSelectFaSetup(i)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**TS Code:**

```
onSelectFaSetup(setup){
    console.log('Fa List' , this.mpFASetupList);
    this.isFaSelected = true;
    this.isCustSelected = false;
    console.log('fa before ' , setup);
    this.dashboardId = setup.mainDashboardId;
    console.log('fa after ' , setup);
}
```

There are the error messages :

**First Click :** 
["Fa List" is the data. (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak8qA.png)

**Second Click :** 
["Fa List" is the data. (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbkeU.png)

As you can see , the data "Fa List" is changing after the click.
Any idea guys why angular is behaving this way ?

**Edit 1 :** This is the mpFASetupList data :

mpFASetupList : [{internalCode: 0, authFlag: false, mainDashboardId: 0, validateStatusFlag: false, statusFlag: false}]

Comment: Please show your `onSelectFaSetup()`

Comment: post your onSelectFaSetup() function as well, it's difficult to identify the issue like this,

Comment: `id="faRadioBtn"` Not sure but make this dynamic or try removing it.

Comment: by setting id on input and pressing radio button inside *ngFor directive you are setting every single instance of radio button. you should remove id or create template driven form or reactive form

Comment: can you show your mpFASetupList model

Comment: It is not allowed to change the single object (i) in a *ngFor , you have to change it via :  mpFASetupList[INDEX]

Comment: so guys here is my onSelectFaSetup() :
`console.log('Fa List' , this.mpFASetupList);
    this.isFaSelected = true;
    this.isCustSelected = false;
    console.log('fa before ' , setup);
    this.dashboardId = setup.mainDashboardId;
    console.log('fa after ' , setup);`
Just setting a bunf of flags and console.logs.

@Jai tried with no id as well , didn't work.
@VinkoVorih I have another table with similar data , that one is working fine , its just this one that troubling me.

Comment: @Chellappan mpFASetupList added in the 1st Edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this behavior , the `<table>` tag in which the `<tr>` tag was placed had a `name` , `[(ngModel)]` and `ngDefaultControl`.

Hence it was behaving like that.
After trimming down these unnecessary attributes , it is behaving as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Well Fa List is a string "on" after you clicked the radio button. Since i don't know what onSelectFaSetup does i can only assume that you change the mpFASetupList to the string "on", which the *ngFor directive can't loop because it's not an array. If you post the method i might help a bit more

Comment: nothing like that is happening in the function :
`console.log('Fa List' , this.mpFASetupList);
    this.isFaSelected = true;
    this.isCustSelected = false;
    console.log('fa before ' , setup);
    this.dashboardId = setup.mainDashboardId;
    console.log('fa after ' , setup);`